# Trigger like $EVT_PARK but when slide change starts

Tags: jssor

I am using $EVT_PARK to change captions but this only triggers when the slide change has completed. I would like to fade between captions during the slide movement. I can build that but need a trigger to activate when each slide change starts rather than finishes. Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use $EVT_POSITION_CHANGE.
You will get actual position.